# Siegel's Mean Value Theorem by Macbeath and Rogers

Tags: lattices, geometry-of-numbers

It is claimed in an answer in mathoverflow to a question about Siegel's Mean value theorem (link- [Siegel's Mean Value Theorem by Rogers and Macbeath](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157087/siegels-mean-value-theorem-by-rogers-and-macbeath)) that there is mistake for the case $n=2$. I couldn't find any mistake in the paper. Is it true that there is a mistake? If so what is it?

Comment: The link you give notes a paper where the mistake is said to have been corrected. Have you looked at that paper?

Comment: "The hardest part in Schmidt’s work was the case $n = 2$ where most of Rogers’s identities were not applicable: there was no variance bound in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to rely upon." --- https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.01433

Comment: @CarloBeenakker The paper that I'm taking about (link-  http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0103183) only considers (Siegel) mean values over space of lattices, not variance. Is it the same paper you're talking about?

Comment: Gerry Myerson No I didn't look at that paper. In the link (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157087/siegels-mean-value-theorem-by-rogers-and-macbeath) it is said Theorem 1, page 147 might be wrong. But as far as I've checked there isn't any mistake in any argument there. I think the mistake that @skayf is talking about in a answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157087/siegels-mean-value-theorem-by-rogers-and-macbeath might be in different paper. To be clear the paper Macbeath and Rogers I'm talking about is-- https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0103183.